# No-IP host site with a dynamic ip adress

Tags: webserver, ip, host

I was searching for a solution about hosting a site with a dynamic IP. Is it possible? I'm just annoyed of re-uploading the code & database dump every time I want to show something to a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this : http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html

Comment: How did you do?